# What's wrong with this sentence "What potential risk would be there for me?"?

Tags: grammaticality

> What potential risk would be there for me?

When I type this sentence, my Grammarly is telling me it's wrong. Why? Just wondering. I am responding to a person who warns me that something risky is happening if I do something.

Comment: It's fine, grammatically speaking. You could lose the adjective, however, with no ill effects: "What risk would there be for me?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

> What potential risk would there be for me?

In this sentence, *there* is functioning as an indefinite pronoun - you are asking whether or not there will be a risk, and if there is, what kind of risk would it be.

This

> What potential risk would be there for me?

is asking *if you go somewhere* (*to* a place referred to by *where*) what risk *would be in that location*.

Comment: Thanks. Very clear answer! The grammar.ly keeps telling me to put `would` in the front. It's really weird.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
what kind of potential risk ....
```

would be better.

Comment: Please support your answer with reasons to why you think you are correct. It will help the OP.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.